# Add to datetimes/times

Tags: sql, sqlite

I try in Sqlite3 something like

```
select datetime(datetime('now') + time('01:00:00'))
```

and

```
select datetime(datetime('now') + datetime('1 days'))
```

but get wrong result `-4707-06-04 10:00:00` - i.e., `-4707` year. Why? IMO Sqlite3 supports +/- of dates/times, right? Where is the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT datetime(datetime('now'), '+1 hour')    
select datetime(datetime('now'), '+1 day')
```

look here for details
https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html